# How do I set custom listview adapter from another class?

Tags: android, class, android-listview, instance, android-context

I want to set a custom listview adapter in my Preferences class with an adapter located in my main class.  When I try:

```
MyActivity.listView.setAdapter(new MyActivity.UserItemAdapter2(Prefs.this, R.layout.listitem, MyActivity.tweets));
```

I get an error stating "No enclosing instance of type MyActivity is accessible." I can't make my adapter class static because it calls `getSystemService`, which is a non-static method.  How do resolve this?  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my adapter class:

```
public class UserItemAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
            private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

            public UserItemAdapter2(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, tweets);
                this.tweets = tweets;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
                }

                Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
                if (tweet != null) {
                    TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
                    TextView message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

                    if (username != null) {
                        username.setText(tweet.username);
                    }

                    if(message != null) {
                        message.setText(tweet.message);
                    }

                    if(image != null) {
                        //image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(tweet.image_url));
                        tango.DisplayImage(tweet.image_url, image);
                    }
                }
                return v;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pull that `Adapter` out into its own file so you can use it from anywhere.

Comment: You need to use the `LayoutInflator` singleton: `v = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem,
                null);`